# Passing a member of a struct to a method of the same struct in Rust

Tags: rust, borrowing

I am now facing a borrowing problem in Rust, and I have an idea to solve it. But I think the way I found is not a good answer. So I am wondering if there is another way to solve it.

I use the following example code to describe my situation:

```
struct S {
    val: u8
}

impl S {
    pub fn f1(&mut self) {
        println!("F1");
        self.f2(self.val);
    }

    pub fn f2(&mut self, input: u8) {
        println!("F2");

        // Do something with input
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S {
        val: 0
    };

    s.f1();
}
```

Structure `S` has a method, `f2`, which takes an additional argument `input` to do something. There is another method, `f1`, which calls `f2` with the `val` of structure `S`. Outsider may call either `f1` or `f2` for different use cases.

When I compiled the above code, I got the following error message:

```
src\main.rs:9:17: 9:25 error: cannot use `self.val` because it was mutably borrowed [E0503]
src\main.rs:9         self.f2(self.val);
                              ^~~~~~~~
src\main.rs:9:9: 9:13 note: borrow of `*self` occurs here
src\main.rs:9         self.f2(self.val);
                      ^~~~
```

I roughly understand how borrowing works in Rust. So I know that I can solve the problem by changing the implementation of `f1` to:

```
pub fn f1(&mut self) {
    let v = self.val;
    println!("F1");
    self.f2(v);
}
```

However, I feel this solution a little bit redundant. I am wondering if there is a way to solve this problem **without using extra variable binding**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution works not because of an extra variable binding, but rather because of an extra *copy*. Integer types can be implicitly copied, so `let v = self.val` creates a copy of the value. That copy is not borrowed from `self` but owned. So compiler allows you to call `f2` with this copy.

If you write `self.f2(self.val)`, compiler will also attempt to make a copy of `self.val`. However, at this location it is not possible to make a copy because `self` is borrowed for the function call. So it is not possible to make such call unless you copy the value before it. And this is not a syntax limitation, but an enforcement of the borrow checker. Anyway, it's better to write the copying and the call in the order in which they actually happen.

If the type you're trying to use as argument were not `Copy` (e.g. a `String`), you would need to write `let v = self.val.clone(); self.f2(v);` to ask the compiler for copy explicitly. Making such calls without making a copy is not allowed. You probably would need to make the method non-mutable or eliminate the argument somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I better copy `self.val` before passing it to `f2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick for copyable values:

```
pub fn f1(&mut self) {
    println!("F1");
    match self.val {x => self.f2(x)};
}
```

However, using an explicit temporary variable is more clear and idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interesting way.